# How create our own NTP pool for internal usage

Tags: linux, ntp

We have one NTP (Linux) server and some services time is synchronizing with the server.
We are going to add another NTP server but we want create pool like public pool in our internal network instead of add new server address to time configuration on each server.
Is that possible or we have to add second address or use DNS record or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

For my case I've enabled Round-Robin dns and added multiple addresses for the same FQDN, yet it doesn't support load balancing but it can work as an HA.
in addition add DNS records for NTP servers like (01.pool.local,02.pool.local)